# Turn Passcode Off grayed out

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

**Context**

I have recently acquired a series 1 Apple Watch. When I first started setting it up, I added a passcode out of habit. Now I want to temporarily disable the passcode as I'm continuing to do a lot of setup *off of my wrist* and it's getting tedious having to enter the code over and over.

**The Problem**

The option to "Turn Passcode Off" is grayed out on both my iPhone (in the Watch app) and on the Apple Watch itself. How do I enable either button in order to disable the passcode?

Comment: Have you already tried to restart either the Apple Watch and the iPhone? If so, I'd suggest you to repair the Apple Watch to your iPhone again and see what happens: make sure you restarted both devices first though.

Comment: Is Apple Pay turned on? Try disabling it.

Comment: Wish I could remember how/if I solved this. Others will have to be the judge of all these suggestions, which I can no longer test. 

Answer (score 2):

Exchange mail and configuration profiles (generally installed by a workplace or school) can also enforce a passcode. To disable the passcode in this case you'll have to either remove the profile or the account.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting in your iphone, general then reset then reset all setting... it will not delete your stuff like pictures video msgs... after setting up your iPhone then unpair and pair your Apple Watch you will not face passcode issue...

Comment: That seems like an awful lot of hassle :/